# ASP.NET location element override behavior

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization, overriding, roles

Assume I have the following in my web.config (most of the file omitted for brevity):

```
<configuration>
  <location path="somefolder/somepage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="SomeRole" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <!-- 
            Lots of other settings.
        -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

If I navigate to somefolder/somepage.aspx, whose access is limited to users in the SomeRole role (and I am a member of that role), what happens with the settings in the commented area?  Do they still apply, even though they are outside the location element where the page is specified?

Comment: I'd guess they're inherited in the location but overriden where specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they still apply, provided that they aren't enclosed in `<location>` elements of their own.